# Android Studio 3.1 Execution failed for task: Error while merging dex archives

Tags: android, build-error, android-studio-3.1

android studio was getting build error while build execution with following

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.

here is my gradle file where i am adding some jar dependency.

App.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.demo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation files('libs/commons-codec-1.4.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-codec-1.9.jar')
    implementation files('libs/opencsv-2.4.jar')
    implementation files('libs/ormlite-android-4.46.jar')
    implementation files('libs/ormlite-core-4.46.jar')
    implementation files('libs/Pushwoosh.jar')
    implementation files('libs/StartAppInApp-2.3.2.jar')
}
```

Project.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: add your build.gradle file and top lavel gradle file here

Comment: i have added my gradle file here.

Comment: Are any of your dependencies using androidx?  There's a ton of this issue in jetpack...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use need to ensure multidex is true in build.gradle.

```
    android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

     defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
         targetSdkVersion 22

         // Enabling multidex support.
         multiDexEnabled true
     }
      }

 dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
   }
```

you can also create a class that extends multidex and that class should be mention in application tag.

Comment: minSDk version is 18. But no luck

Comment: @Godwin post your gradle file